# Unlock phone when home button is pressed

Tags: android, button

I have the power key almost broken on my phone, so it's kind of a nightmare to lock/unlock the phone

I know how to lock the phone programmaticaly with an icon for instance on the screen, but the question comes when I try to unlock it. I've thought that the best possible way to do it is that when I press the home button (which is a capacitive button) the phone wakes up, but I don't know how to do so

So my question is, is that possible? and how it's done??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

to override Home Button function, You have to download the app [button remapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=22e00d0d713aaaccb45c3f60d17e63ae&attachmentid=467998&d=1292740886) and use it to change the Home key functionality.

---

And if it not worked(as happens in a lot of cases) follow the following steps:

**1-** download any file explorer app, like [ES Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en).

**2-** open the app and enable **Root Explorer** inside it.

**3-** go to the file `system/user/keylayout/Generic.kl`.

**4-** open the permissions of the file and change it to **read** and **write** in order to be able to change it.

**5-** search for the line that contains the Home Button code(you can find it by easily notice the word Home key in it, or by easily finding its value through **button remapper** app)

**6-** comment this line, in order to be able to change the Button functionality within any app programmatically(this can be done by overriding the back button by `onBackPressed()` function, as the Home button will be considered as a Back button in this case), or change its command to do what you want it to achieve(just look through the file for the command that you wish and copy/paste it instead of the `MOVE_HOME` command).

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm not saying that it's not right but what I want is some information about the code that I need to develop in order to do so

Comment: the point here is where you want that to be happen?!! in the entire device or through a specific app.

Comment: In the entire device, I think that must be done with an IntentService right?

Comment: why to create a service?!! if you just want it through the entire device, just use my way, its a straightforward way that gives you what you want through the entire device. You don't need any coding at all if you used my way, just use the second option in the sixth point.